# Argparse unrecognized argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

What I want:

```
python main.py --num_epochs 200
```

What I get:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [--data_type DATA_TYPE]
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --num_epochs 200
```

Original Code:

```
import argparse
# Importing the libraries
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import sample
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.parallel
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import BatchSampler, SequentialSampler
import pickle
from model import *
from data_loader import get_loader

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# data
parser.add_argument('--mode', type=str, default="train", help='train / test')
parser.add_argument('--data_type', type=str, default="ml_100k")
parser.add_argument('--model-path', type=str, default="./models")
parser.add_argument('--data-path', type=str, default="./data")
parser.add_argument('--data-shuffle', type=bool, default=True)
parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=512)
parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', type=int, default=100)
parser.add_argument('--val-step', type=int, default=5)
parser.add_argument('--test-epoch', type=int, default=50)
parser.add_argument('--start-epoch', type=int, default=0)
parser.add_argument('--neg-cnt', type=int, default=100)
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.01)
parser.add_argument('--beta1', type=float, default=0.5, help='beta1 for Adam optimizer')
parser.add_argument('--beta2', type=float, default=0.999, help='beta2 for Adam optimizer')
parser.add_argument('--dropout', type=float, default=0.7)
parser.add_argument('--n_critic', type=int, default=5, help='number of D updates per each G update')

parser.add_argument('--emb-dim', type=int, default=32)
parser.add_argument('--hidden', default=[64,32,16, 8])
parser.add_argument('--nb', type=int, default=2)

parser.add_argument('--train_path', '-train',type=str, default='/rating_0.pkl')#train.pkl')
parser.add_argument('--val_path','-val', type=str, default='/rating_1.pkl')#val.pkl')
parser.add_argument('--test_path', '-test',type=str, default='/rating_2.pkl')#test.pkl')

args = parser.parse_args()




############
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Load the datas
num_users, num_items, num_classes, num_side_features, num_features,\
u_features, v_features, u_features_side, v_features_side = get_loader(args.data_type)

u_features = torch.from_numpy(u_features).to(device).float()
v_features = torch.from_numpy(v_features).to(device).float()
u_features_side = torch.from_numpy(u_features_side).to(device)
v_features_side = torch.from_numpy(v_features_side).to(device)
rating_train = torch.load('./data/'+args.data_type+args.train_path).to(device)
rating_val = torch.load('./data/'+args.data_type+args.val_path).to(device)
rating_test = torch.load('./data/'+args.data_type+args.test_path).to(device)

# Creating the architecture of the Neural Network
model = GAE(num_users, num_items, num_classes,
            num_side_features, args.nb,
            u_features, v_features, u_features_side, v_features_side,
            num_users+num_items, args.emb_dim, args.hidden, args.dropout)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()
"""Print out the network information."""
num_params = 0
for p in model.parameters():
    num_params += p.numel()
print(model)
print("The number of parameters: {}".format(num_params))

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = args.lr, betas=[args.beta1, args.beta2])

best_epoch = 0
best_loss  = 9999.

def reset_grad():
    """Reset the gradient buffers."""
    optimizer.zero_grad()

def train():
    global best_loss, best_epoch
    if args.start_epoch:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(args.model_path,
                              'model-%d.pkl'%(args.start_epoch))).state_dict())

    # Training
    for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.num_epochs):
        model.train()

        train_loss = 0.
        train_rmse = 0.
        for s, u in enumerate(BatchSampler(SequentialSampler(sample(range(num_users), num_users)),
                              batch_size=num_users, drop_last=False)):
                              #batch_size=args.batch_size, drop_last=False)):
            u = torch.from_numpy(np.array(u)).to(device)

            for t, v in enumerate(BatchSampler(SequentialSampler(sample(range(num_items), num_items)),
                                  batch_size=num_items, drop_last=False)):
                                  #batch_size=args.batch_size, drop_last=False)):
                v = torch.from_numpy(np.array(v)).to(device)
                if len(torch.nonzero(torch.index_select(torch.index_select(rating_train, 1, u), 2, v))) == 0:
                    continue

                m_hat, loss_ce, loss_rmse = model(u, v, rating_train)

                reset_grad()
                loss_ce.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                train_loss += loss_ce.item()
                train_rmse += loss_rmse.item()

        log = 'epoch: '+str(epoch+1)+' loss_ce: '  +str(train_loss/(s+1)/(t+1)) \
                                    +' loss_rmse: '+str(train_rmse/(s+1)/(t+1))
        print(log)

        if (epoch+1) % args.val_step == 0:
            # Validation
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                u = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(num_users))).to(device)
                v = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(num_items))).to(device)
                m_hat, loss_ce, loss_rmse = model(u, v, rating_val)

            print('[val loss] : '+str(loss_ce.item())+
                  ' [val rmse] : '+str(loss_rmse.item()))
            if best_loss > loss_rmse.item():
                best_loss = loss_rmse.item()
                best_epoch= epoch+1
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(args.model_path, 'model-%d.pkl'%(best_epoch)))

def test():
    # Test
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(args.model_path,
                          'model-%d.pkl'%(best_epoch))))
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        u = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(num_users))).to(device)
        v = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(num_items))).to(device)
        m_hat, loss_ce, loss_rmse = model(u, v, rating_test)

    print('[test loss] : '+str(loss_ce.item()) +
          ' [test rmse] : '+str(loss_rmse.item()))

def predict():
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(args.model_path,
                          'model-%d.pkl'%(best_epoch))))
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        u = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(num_users))).to(device)
        v = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(num_items))).to(device)
        _,_,_, mhat = model.predict(u, v, rating_train)
    return mhat

#main()
dataset=args.data_type
if args.mode == 'train':
    train()
elif args.mode == 'test':
    best_epoch = args.test_epoch
test()
mhat=predict()
torch.save(mhat, 'mhat.pt')
```

But if I move the `argparse` part to test.py, the sub-component miraculously work:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# data
parser.add_argument('--mode', type=str, default="train", help='train / test')
parser.add_argument('--data_type', type=str, default="ml_100k")
parser.add_argument('--model-path', type=str, default="./models")
parser.add_argument('--data-path', type=str, default="./data")
parser.add_argument('--data-shuffle', type=bool, default=True)
parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=512)
parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', type=int, default=100)
parser.add_argument('--val-step', type=int, default=5)
parser.add_argument('--test-epoch', type=int, default=50)
parser.add_argument('--start-epoch', type=int, default=0)
parser.add_argument('--neg-cnt', type=int, default=100)
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.01)
parser.add_argument('--beta1', type=float, default=0.5, help='beta1 for Adam optimizer')
parser.add_argument('--beta2', type=float, default=0.999, help='beta2 for Adam optimizer')
parser.add_argument('--dropout', type=float, default=0.7)
parser.add_argument('--n_critic', type=int, default=5, help='number of D updates per each G update')

parser.add_argument('--emb-dim', type=int, default=32)
parser.add_argument('--hidden', default=[64,32,16, 8])
parser.add_argument('--nb', type=int, default=2)

parser.add_argument('--train_path', '-train',type=str, default='/rating_0.pkl')#train.pkl')
parser.add_argument('--val_path','-val', type=str, default='/rating_1.pkl')#val.pkl')
parser.add_argument('--test_path', '-test',type=str, default='/rating_2.pkl')#test.pkl')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.num_epochs)
```

> python test.py --num_epochs 200
>
> 200

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* example. Very little of this code should be necessary to reproduce your problem, and eliminating the irrelevant code (all the `torch`-related stuff) may make the difference clear.

Comment: @chepner I have already pinpointed the cause--`import data_loader` brings this strange behavior. Code is available at https://github.com/zjplab/gc-mc-pytorch. `test.py` demonstrates this.

Comment: SInce the usage does not match your parser, my guess is that there's another parser looking at the same command line.  Maybe in something that you import.